# I want to add data validator in my signup from dynamically

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want display error in input field separately in signup from. but after submitting with invalid inputs page redirect to same page but no errors are displayed in the input. i have written my code like:

**in Signup from**

```
forms={}
if form.errors:
    for key,value in form.errors.items():
        forms[key]=value

return render(request, 'signup.html',{'forms':forms})
```

**in template**

```
<script>
{% for key,value in forms.items %}
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name={{key}}]').parent().addClass("alert-validate");
        $('input[name={{key}}]').parent().attr("data-validate", "{{value | safe}}");
    });
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because from form.errors.items() value is given in ul and li tags
try following in signup

```
if form.errors:
   for key in form.errors:
       forms[key]=(form.errors[key])[0]
return render(request, 'signup.html',{'forms':forms})
```